# Confusion with nested loop and setting ranges

Tags: vba, nested-loops

I am struggling to create the nested loop necessary my first effort at such.

I need to assign the ID value to the cell in the source column when it matches the cell value in the email column.

i.e from the email column the first cell value is bobjohnson@email.com his ID value is 0 I need to find all the cells with bobjohnson@email.com in the Source column and assign them 0

I know I have a mish-mash of stuff in here, but after a couple hours of tiring I though ask for help

Thank you

```
Sub Source()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Integer
Dim lrow As Long
Dim Myfind As String
Dim Idvalue As String
Dim firstaddress As String
Dim c
lrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C65336").End(xlUp).Row
With Worksheets(2)
    For i = 1 To lrow
        Myfind = Cells(i, 3).Text
        Idvalue = Cells(i, 2).Value
        Set c = Range("A:A").Find(Myfind, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstaddress = c.Address
            Do
                Range("MyFind").Select
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Idvalue
                Set c = Range("A:A").FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstaddress
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Original File

```
email                     ID   Source
bobjohnson@email.com      0    pollypots@email.com
bobjohnson@email.com      0    juanalvarez@email.com
frankcarpet@email.com     1    bettysue@email.com
juanalvarez@email.com     2    bobjohnson@email.com
juanalvarez@email.com     2    bettysue@email.com
sallybersong@email.com    3    Juanalvarez@email.com
sallybersong@email.com    3    yaraflowers@email.com
pollypots@email.com       4    yaraflowers@email.com
yaraflowers@email.com     5    juanalvarez@email.com
yaraflowers@email.com     5    pollypots@email.com
yaraflowers@email.com     5    bobjohnson@email.com
yaraflowers@email.com     5    bettysue@email.com
bettysue@email.com        6    yaraflowers@email.com
```

Results File

```
email                     ID   Source
bobjohnson@email.com      0    4
bobjohnson@email.com      0    2
frakkcarpet@email.com     1    6
juanalvarez@email.com     2    0
juanalvarez@email.com     2    6
sallybersong@email.com    3    2
sallybersong@email.com    3    5
pollypots@email.com       4    5
yaraflowers@email.com     5    2
yaraflowers@email.com     5    4
yaraflowers@email.com     5    0
yaraflowers@email.com     5    6
bettysue@email.com        6    5
```

Comment: Do you really need a VBA solution? This would be easy with a VLOOKUP.

Comment: VLOOKUP returns the first found instance, so the source of one address would be the same every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the number and order of e-mails in first column of both blocks is the same. You need to modify this of course, because I put all data in one worksheet in columns A to F.

```
Sub Source()
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lLastRow
    Range("F" & i).Value = Range("D:D").Find(Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 2).Value).Offset(0, 1).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

By the way, here

```
Range("MyFind").Select
```

you are referring to a named range called `MyFind`. I doubt this was your intention.

Comment: Thank you Kapol this is a big help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want to achieve here is to find the id according to the relationship between column A and B, and then replace the email with id in Column C. By reading your code, I suspect that you are using the wrong column to find the email address. I modified several lines on top of your codes, and here is the answer which could achieve your result shown as above.

```
Sub Source()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Integer
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim Myfind As Variant
Dim Idvalue As Variant
Dim firstaddress As String
Dim c As Range
lrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C65336").End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets("Sheet2")

For i = 2 To lrow
    Myfind = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Idvalue = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Set c = Range("C:c").Find(Myfind, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Value = Idvalue
            Set c = Range("c:c").FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing


    End If
Next i

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that is one of the things I was doing wrong, thank you. Your explanation of what I was asking for was way better then mine!